# How to send image as JSON to tensorflow_model_server?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, resnet

I have trained resnet with an additional layer to predict a dog vs cat model and serving it from localhost using

```
tensorflow_model_server --port=8500 --rest_api_port=8501 \
                        --model_name=resnet_model \
                        --model_base_path=/home/pc3/deep_learning/models/resnet
```

`$ saved_model_cli show --all --dir resnet/1` shows this signature:

```
MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'serve' contains the following SignatureDefs:

signature_def['__saved_model_init_op']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['__saved_model_init_op'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INVALID
        shape: unknown_rank
        name: NoOp
  Method name is: 

signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['keras_layer_1_input'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 256, 256, 3)
        name: serving_default_keras_layer_1_input:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['dense_2'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 2)
        name: StatefulPartitionedCall:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict

Concrete Functions:
  Function Name: '__call__'
    Option #1
      Callable with:
        Argument #1
          inputs: TensorSpec(shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='inputs')
        Argument #2
          DType: bool
          Value: False
        Argument #3
          DType: NoneType
          Value: None
    Option #2
      Callable with:
        Argument #1
          keras_layer_1_input: TensorSpec(shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='keras_layer_1_input')
        Argument #2
          DType: bool
          Value: True
        Argument #3
          DType: NoneType
          Value: None
    Option #3
      Callable with:
        Argument #1
          inputs: TensorSpec(shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='inputs')
        Argument #2
          DType: bool
          Value: True
        Argument #3
          DType: NoneType
          Value: None
    Option #4
      Callable with:
        Argument #1
          keras_layer_1_input: TensorSpec(shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='keras_layer_1_input')
        Argument #2
          DType: bool
          Value: False
        Argument #3
          DType: NoneType
          Value: None

  Function Name: '_default_save_signature'
    Option #1
      Callable with:
        Argument #1
          keras_layer_1_input: TensorSpec(shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='keras_layer_1_input')

  Function Name: 'call_and_return_all_conditional_losses'
    Option #1
      Callable with:
        Argument #1
          keras_layer_1_input: TensorSpec(shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='keras_layer_1_input')
        Argument #2
          DType: bool
          Value: False
        Argument #3
          DType: NoneType
          Value: None
    Option #2
      Callable with:
        Argument #1
          keras_layer_1_input: TensorSpec(shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='keras_layer_1_input')
        Argument #2
          DType: bool
          Value: True
        Argument #3
          DType: NoneType
          Value: None
    Option #3
      Callable with:
        Argument #1
          inputs: TensorSpec(shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='inputs')
        Argument #2
          DType: bool
          Value: False
        Argument #3
          DType: NoneType
          Value: None
    Option #4
      Callable with:
        Argument #1
          inputs: TensorSpec(shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='inputs')
        Argument #2
          DType: bool
          Value: True
        Argument #3
          DType: NoneType
          Value: None
```

When post request with JSON to `http://localhost:8501/models/resnet_model/1` with this body:

```
{
  "signature_name": "serving_default", 
  "instances": [{"b64": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAA..."}]
}
```

where `iVBORw0KGgoAAAA...` is base64 encoded value of a PNG image which I've already resized to `256x256`, I get this error in response:

```
{
  "error": "Failed to process element: 0 of 'instances' list. Error: INVALID_ARGUMENT: JSON Value: {\n    \"b64\": \"iVBORw0KGgoAAAA...\"\n} Type: Object is not of expected type: float"
}
```

and when I try `"signature_name": "__saved_model_init_op",`  instead, I get

```
{
  "error": "Failed to get input map for signature: __saved_model_init_op"
}
```

After tons of googling, I could not find any tutorial or code example about this particular scenario. So I'm left clueless what is the correct way of post an image to this model?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [resnet_client](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/resnet_client.py#L61).

According to the `signature_def` of your model, it does not accept input as base64, so `MODEL_ACCEPT_JPG` is `False` for your case. follow the link to see how data is sent to the server.